# filling the gaps in a table

Tags: arrays, r, date, time

I have two tables. one has info from 2012 till 2014 with the period of 3 hours. It looks like this:

```
1   01.06.2012 00:00    10  0   
2   01.06.2012 03:00    10  0   
3   01.06.2012 06:00    10  6   
4   01.06.2012 09:00    7,5 0   
5   01.06.2012 12:00    6   2,5 
6   01.06.2012 15:00    6   0   
7   01.06.2012 18:00    4   0   
8   01.06.2012 21:00    4   0   
9   02.06.2012 00:00    0   0   
10  02.06.2012 03:00    0   0
```

The other table is the same time but with the period of 1 minute and it has no data.

```
1   01.06.2012 00:00    3   1   
2   01.06.2012 00:01    3   1   
3   01.06.2012 00:01    3   1   
4   01.06.2012 00:03    3   1   
5   01.06.2012 00:03    3   1   
6   01.06.2012 00:05    3   1   
7   01.06.2012 00:05    3   1   
8   01.06.2012 00:07    3   1   
9   01.06.2012 00:08    3   1   
10  01.06.2012 00:09    3   1   
11  01.06.2012 00:10    3   1
```

Now, I need the values of 2nd and 3rd rows of the second table to correlate to the first, so that if a timestamp from the second table is between `timestamp(i)` and `timestamp(i+1)` of the first table it will take the `B(i)` and `C(i)` and copy them. 
I have this code, but as you can see from above it doesn't put the right values in. `3 & 1` instead of `10 & 0`.

```
clouds <- read.csv('~/2012-2014 clouds info.csv', sep=";", header = FALSE)
cloudFull <- read.csv('~/2012-2014 clouds.csv', sep=";", header = FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(cloudFull)){
  dateOne <- strptime(cloudFull[i,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

  for (j in 1:nrow(clouds)){
    bottomDate = strptime(clouds[j,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    upperDate = strptime(clouds[j+1,1], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
    if  ((dateOne >= bottomDate) && (dateOne < upperDate)) {
      cloudFull[i,2] <- clouds[j,2]
      cloudFull[i,3] <- clouds[j,3]
      break

    } 

  }
}

write.csv(cloudFull, file = 'cc.csv')
```

what do I do?

Comment: assuming that the second data set is cloudFull, your code is working for me and gives the desired results. one problem with writing loops like this is that they have a side effect of cluttering your workspace, so maybe another variable is causing problems. restart your session or remove all your variables and start fresh

Comment: tried doing that, still comes with the same results. I don't even understand where it takes the 3 and 1 from.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful:

```
ddf = rbind(df1, df2)
ddf$V2 = as.Date(as.character(ddf$V2), format="%d.%m.%Y")
ddf = cbind(ddf, do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(ddf$V3),':')))
ddf = ddf[order(ddf$"1",ddf$"2"),]
ddf = ddf[!duplicated(ddf$V3),]
ddf
   V1         V2    V3 V4 V5  1  2
1   1 2012-06-01 00:00 10  0 00 00
12  2 2012-06-01 00:01  3  1 00 01
14  4 2012-06-01 00:03  3  1 00 03
16  6 2012-06-01 00:05  3  1 00 05
18  8 2012-06-01 00:07  3  1 00 07
19  9 2012-06-01 00:08  3  1 00 08
20 10 2012-06-01 00:09  3  1 00 09
21 11 2012-06-01 00:10  3  1 00 10
2   2 2012-06-01 03:00 10  0 03 00
3   3 2012-06-01 06:00 10  6 06 00
4   4 2012-06-01 09:00  7  5 09 00
5   5 2012-06-01 12:00  6  2 12 00
6   6 2012-06-01 15:00  6  0 15 00
7   7 2012-06-01 18:00  4  0 18 00
8   8 2012-06-01 21:00  4  0 21 00
```

Columns '1' and '2' are from V3 and can easily be removed with command:

```
ddf = ddf[,-c(6,7)]
```

Comment: but if you look at V4 past the first row it's still incorrect? I don't get where the 3 and 1 come from.